# _csrf always NULL and isAnonymous() always FALSE (after deployment)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm having a strange issue (Spring 5.0.8, Spring Boot 2.0.5) with our project. When I run it locally in my Eclipse env it works perfectly. With "it", I mean the expression

```
<security:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
    <li class="navbar-item"><a href="/signin">
        <spring:message code="menu.signin" />
    </a></li>
</security:authorize>
```

is evaluated fine, as long the user is not logged in, he/she is Anonymous. This code is in our app for 6 months now and worked perfectly.

As I made a quite a lot of changes to our logging mechanisms and started to switch part of the project to Thymeleaf (everything works fine) I built finally a new WAR with Maven and deployed it to EBS.

Now, it seems that not only

```
<security:authorize ...>
```

is not working anymore, the _csrf-Tags, which are evaluated using

```
<meta th:name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}" />
<meta th:name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}" />
```

cannot be evaluated (only on the EBS environment - locally everything is fine).

I started to trace the problem in the logs and discovered that the expression above lead to an exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1007E: Property or field 'token' cannot be found on null
```

which might be obivous when _csrf is null.

**Question**: Has anyone ever had kind of similar problem? I am not expecting an answer to my problem here, but I am wondering why everything might work perfectly on my local setup and not working anymore when published on EBS?

Might there be an issue with my configuration (annotation based) and the variables/beans in Spring cannot be evaluated when published?

As the JSP example from above is not working (and the Thymeleaf code as well), I am expecting this is a Spring backend issue and not a Thymeleaf problem.

Thank you for any suggestions on this.

Comment: Why are you deploying a WAR file? If you are using Thymeleaf that shouldn't be needed anymore. Looks like security isn't enabled (for whatever reason) on the EBS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>As so often, after posting the question to Stackoverflow I found the reason for the erratic behaviour of the app. I had declared @EnableAutoConfiguration in another @Controller class which might have led to some confusion. After removing the declaration everything works perfect.</strike>

Actually I figured out (again) what the reason for the behaviour is. After eliminating the second EnableAutoConfiguration and building a WAR (we still have some JSP inside the app) everything was working fine. I then made some fixes, redeployed the WAR and the problem was the same again.

After [finding some indication](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-war-structure.html) that the included spring-boot-starter-tomcat might interfere with the deployment, adding

```
<dependencies>
..
..
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

did the job.